# DateDiff() syntax error in sql server computed column formula Section

Tags: datediff

```
UPDATE tblInventoryOrders
SET tblInventoryOrders.Remaining_Arrival_WorkDays = DateDiff(Day,[Ordered_Date],[Estimated_Arrival_Date]);

Column data Type
Remaining_Arrival_WorkDays int
Ordered_Date datetime
Estimated_Arrival_Date datetime
```

I have attempted to add the above query in the sql server computed column formula section, but continues to display an error while saving the formula. Yet, running the query itself works fine. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A computed column is part of a table's definition so you need an alter table statement, such as:

```
alter table tblInventoryOrders
add [Remaining_Arrival_WorkDays] as (DateDiff(Day,[Ordered_Date],[Estimated_Arrival_Date]))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ad85/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblInventoryOrders
    ([Ordered_Date] datetime, [Estimated_Arrival_Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO tblInventoryOrders
    ([Ordered_Date], [Estimated_Arrival_Date])
VALUES
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-02-01 00:00:00')
;

alter table tblInventoryOrders
add [Remaining_Arrival_WorkDays] as (DateDiff(Day,[Ordered_Date],[Estimated_Arrival_Date]))
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from tblInventoryOrders
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ad85/1/0)**:

```
|         Ordered_Date | Estimated_Arrival_Date | Remaining_Arrival_WorkDays |
|----------------------|------------------------|----------------------------|
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |   2017-02-01T00:00:00Z |                         31 |
```